# Update a database table Column to current date based on GridView Cell value changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm inserting dataset on load to a cache

```
{
    string command = @"SELECT Item, Location1, UpdatedLoc1, Loation2, UpdatedLoc2 FROM Stock";
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command, con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds, "Stock");
    ds.Tables["Stock"].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { ds.Tables["Stock"].Columns["Item"] };
    Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds);
    gvStockItems.DataSource = ds;
    gvStockItems.DataBind();
}
```

and on GridView updating event I'm updating the cache

```
if (Cache["DATASET"] != null)
{
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["DATASET"];
    DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Stock"].Rows.Find(e.Keys["Item"]);
    dr["Location1"] = e.NewValues["Location1"];
    dr["Location2"] = e.NewValues["Location2"];
    Cache.Insert("DATASET", ds);
    gvStockItems.EditIndex = -1;
    GetDataFromCache();
}
```

and then saving data back to the database using `da.Update()` as

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Item, Location1, UpdatedLoc1, Loation2, UpdatedLoc2  FROM Stock", con);
    DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["DATASET"];
    string UpdateQuery = "UPDATE Stock SET Location1=@Location1, Loation2 =@Loation2 WHERE Item=@Item";
    SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, con);
    update.Parameters.Add("@Item", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50, "Item");
    update.Parameters.Add("@Location1", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Location1");
    update.Parameters.Add("@Loation2 ", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Loation2");
    da.UpdateCommand = update;
    da.Update(ds, "Stock");                
}
```

I need to update database table column `UpdatedLoc1` to **Current Date** if the value of `Location1` modified and `UpdatedLoc2` Column if `Location2` value modified.

How to achieve this using the `RowState` change method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Near the location that you do

```
dr["Location1"] = e.NewValues["Location1"];
```

You should compare the old value with the new value and set the UpdatedLoc1 date column accordingly. If you do the check before updating Location1 then you can compared the DataSet value and the NewValues value. If you do it afterwards you can ask the DataRow for the original value and the new value to work out if a change has been made, e.g with `dr["Location1", DataRowVersion.Original]` - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.item?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataRow_Item_System_String_System_Data_DataRowVersion_